# Angular Dynamic Reactive Form Nested FormArray for Radios Buttons

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

On API call I have an Array of questions and their options JSON.

```
 [
  {
    "QuestionText": "Question goes here...",
    "AnswerChoice": [
      {
        "text": "text1",
        "answerId": "1"
      },
      {
        "text": "text2",
        "answerId": "2"
      },
      {
        "text": "text3",
        "answerId": "3"
      },
      {
        "text": "text4",
        "answerId": "4"
      },
      {
        "text": "text5",
        "answerId": "5"
      }
    ],
    "questionId": "1"
  },
  {
    "QuestionText": "Second question goes here...?",
    "AnswerChoice": [
      {
        "text": "text1",
        "answerId": "1"
      },
      {
        "text": "text2",
        "answerId": "2"
      },
      {
        "text": "text3",
        "answerId": "3"
      },
      {
        "text": "text4",
        "answerId": "4"
      },
      {
        "text": "text5",
        "answerId": "5"
      }
    ],
    "questionId": "2"
  }
  ... and so on.
]
```

Answer choices are radio buttons in UI.

So, now the question.

I am trying to build a Reactive Form for this problem. I am not able to come up with a solution. I am trying to build nested FormArrays but in vain.

My attempts to solve this problem:

HTML -

```
        <form [formGroup]="eidFormSubmission">
        <div>
            <div *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index">
                <p>
                    {{i+1}}. {{question.QuestionText}}
                </p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio"
                            *ngFor="let answer of question.AnswerChoice let k=index">
                            {{question.questionId}}
                            <input [value]="answer.answerId" type="radio" formControlName="i"
                                id="{{question.questionId}}" name="quesAnswer"
                                class="custom-control-input">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{question.questionId}}">
                                {{ answer.text }}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button (click)="onSubmitAnswers()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
    </form>
```

TS -

```
  eidFormSubmissionInit(){
    const formArray = this.formBuilder.array([]);
    this.eidFormSubmission = this.formBuilder.group({
      questions: formArray
    })
  }
```

Now I am confused about how to push dynamically (after API response) into formbuilder.

And second problem is with the radio button when I select an option from the second question it deselects from the first question.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try to create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) example to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

First create a form like this with "questions" inside as a FormArray:

```
this.eidFormSubmission = this.fb.group({
  questions: this.fb.array([])
});
```

after in your ngOnInit when your receive questions, loop through each question and add a new item into "questions" formArray

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getQuestions().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.questions = data;

      this.questions.forEach(question => {
        (this.eidFormSubmission.get('questions') as FormArray).push(this.addQuestionFormGroup(question));
      });
    });
  }
```

with this utility function:

```
  private addQuestionFormGroup(question: any): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      QuestionText: question.QuestionText,
      AnswerChoice: new FormControl()
    });
  }
```

html markup:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitAnswers()" [formGroup]="eidFormSubmission">
  <table>
    <tr formArrayName="questions" *ngFor="let data of eidFormSubmission.get('questions').controls; let i = index">
      <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
        <th>
          <input type="text" formControlName="QuestionText" readonly>
        </th>
        <th *ngFor="let answer of questions[i].AnswerChoice">
          <input type="radio" formControlName="AnswerChoice" value="{{answer.answerId}}">{{answer.text}}
        </th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-692cyt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the self-explanatory answer, it also helps me clear my basic concept about ng forms.